# Android, ksopa2 - ParametersList

Tags: android, xml, soap, веб-служба

Здравствуйте.
В гугле решения не нашел, смекалкой не сообразил(пока что).
Надо послать запрос со списком параметров следующего вида:

```
<ParameterList>
<Parameter Name="Склад" Value="111" Type="Справочник.Склады" TypeSearch = "Код"></Parameter>
<Parameter Name="Номенклатура" Value="222" Type="Справочник.Номенклатура" TypeSearch = "Код"></Parameter>
<Parameter Name="Приоритет" Value="0" Type="" TypeSearch = ""></Parameter>
</ParameterList>
```

Так как у меня WSDL и android - я использую ksopa2-android. B спокойно получается отправлять запросы с одним простым параметром. Но как вложить вот такой вот список я не знаю.
  Если у кого то был подобный опыт, пожалуйста поделитесь хотя бы ссылкой на то как составляется подобный параметр.

Изучив *wsdl*-файл составил следующий код:

```
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(Auth.NAMESPACE, (String) paramRequest.get("2"));

            StringBuffer bufferProxyAuth = new StringBuffer(paramRequest.get("4") + ":");
            bufferProxyAuth.append(paramRequest.get("5"));
            byte[] bytes1 = bufferProxyAuth.toString().getBytes();
            bufferProxyAuth.setLength(0);
            bufferProxyAuth.append("Basic ");
            org.kobjects.base64.Base64.encode(bytes1, 0, bytes1.length, bufferProxyAuth);

            List<HeaderProperty> headers = new ArrayList<HeaderProperty>();
            headers.add(new HeaderProperty("Authorization", bufferProxyAuth.toString()));
            headers.add(new HeaderProperty("Cookie", (String) paramRequest.get("6")));

            PropertyInfo textQuery = new PropertyInfo();
            textQuery.setName("Name");
            textQuery.setType(PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS);
            //Задаем параметр где находится название метода
            textQuery.setValue((String) paramRequest.get("8"));
            request.addProperty(textQuery);

            //Работа с комплексными типами
            ParametrBox selectBox = (ParametrBox) paramRequest.get("9");//отбор

            ParameterList selectList = new ParameterList(Auth.NAMESPACE_COMPLEX_TYPE, "DimensionsSelect");

            for (Object item : selectBox.getList()) {

                    Parameter parameter = new Parameter(Auth.NAMESPACE, "Parameter");
                    // parameter.addAttribute("Name",(((ParameterCus)item).getName()));
                    PropertyInfo propertyName = new PropertyInfo();
                    propertyName.setName("Name");
                    propertyName.setType(PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS);
                    propertyName.setValue((((ParameterCus) item).getName()));
                    parameter.addProperty(propertyName);
                    PropertyInfo propertyValue = new PropertyInfo();
                    propertyValue.setName("Value");
                    propertyValue.setType(PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS);
                    propertyValue.setValue((((ParameterCus) item).getValue()));
                    parameter.addProperty(propertyValue);
                    //parameter.addAttribute("Value",(((ParameterCus)item).getValue()));

                    PropertyInfo propertyType = new PropertyInfo();
                    propertyType.setName("Type");
                    propertyType.setType(PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS);
                    propertyType.setValue((((ParameterCus) item).getType()));
                    parameter.addProperty(propertyType);
                    // parameter.addAttribute("Type",(((ParameterCus)item).getType()));
                    PropertyInfo propertyTypeSearch = new PropertyInfo();
                    propertyTypeSearch.setName("TypeSearch");
                    propertyTypeSearch.setType(PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS);
                    propertyTypeSearch.setValue((((ParameterCus) item).getTypeSearch()));
                    parameter.addProperty(propertyTypeSearch);
                    //parameter.addAttribute("TypeSearch",(((ParameterCus)item).getTypeSearch()));

                    selectList.addSoapObject(parameter);

            }
            request.addSoapObject(selectList);

            ParametrBox insertBox = (ParametrBox) paramRequest.get("10");//вставка
            ParameterList inserList = new ParameterList(Auth.NAMESPACE_COMPLEX_TYPE, "DimensionsResources");

            for (Object item : insertBox.getList()) {

                Parameter parameter = new Parameter(Auth.NAMESPACE, "Parameter");
                PropertyInfo propertyName = new PropertyInfo();
                propertyName.setName("Name");
                propertyName.setType(PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS);
                propertyName.setValue((((ParameterCus) item).getName()));
                parameter.addProperty(propertyName);
                PropertyInfo propertyValue = new PropertyInfo();
                propertyValue.setName("Value");
                propertyValue.setType(PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS);
                propertyValue.setValue((((ParameterCus) item).getValue()));
                parameter.addProperty(propertyValue);
                //parameter.addAttribute("Value",(((ParameterCus)item).getValue()));
                PropertyInfo propertyType = new PropertyInfo();
                propertyType.setName("Type");
                propertyType.setType(PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS);
                propertyType.setValue((((ParameterCus) item).getType()));
                parameter.addProperty(propertyType);
                // parameter.addAttribute("Type",(((ParameterCus)item).getType()));
                PropertyInfo propertyTypeSearch = new PropertyInfo();
                propertyTypeSearch.setName("TypeSearch");
                propertyTypeSearch.setType(PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS);
                propertyTypeSearch.setValue((((ParameterCus) item).getTypeSearch()));
                parameter.addProperty(propertyTypeSearch);
                //parameter.addAttribute("TypeSearch",(((ParameterCus)item).getTypeSearch()));

                inserList.addSoapObject(parameter);


            }
            request.addSoapObject(inserList);
```

В ответ получаю вот такую ошибку:

```
SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Client' faultstring: 'Неизвестная ошибка. Ошибка преобразования данных XDTO:
Чтение объекта типа: {http://ws1c.xxxxx.ru/objects}ParameterList - [1,223]
Проверка дополнительного свойства:
    форма: Элемент
    имя: {http://ws1c.xxxxxx.ru}Parameter
по причине:
Ошибка преобразования данных XDTO:
Чтение объекта типа: {http://ws1c.xxxxxx.ru/objects}ParameterList - [1,223]
Проверка дополнительного свойства:
    форма: Элемент
    имя: {http://ws1c.xxxxx.ru}Parameter
по причине:
Ошибка проверки данных XDTO:
Структура объекта не соответствует типу: {http://ws1c.xxxxx.ru/objects}ParameterList
' faultactor: 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@29624c4b
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вызов метода происходит со следующими параметрами и следующим ответом:

```
<xs:element name="ModifyInformationRegister">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="DimensionsSelect" type="xs1:ParameterList"/>
<xs:element name="DimensionsResources" type="xs1:ParameterList" nillable="true"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="ModifyInformationRegisterResponse">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="return" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

В свою очередь, типы параметров передаваемых методу следующие:

```
<xs:complexType name="Parameter">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="Value" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="Type" type="xs:string" nillable="true"/>
<xs:element name="TypeSearch" type="xs:string" nillable="true"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="ParameterList">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="Parameter" type="tns:Parameter" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Чтобы добиться успешного результата от webservice'а и получить заветную простую строку "Ок" мне подошел следующий код:

```
                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(Auth.NAMESPACE, SOAP_METHOD);

                PropertyInfo textQuery = new PropertyInfo();
                textQuery.setName("Name");
                textQuery.setType(PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS);
                //Задаем параметр где находится название метода(просто строка)
                textQuery.setValue("имя метода");
                request.addProperty(textQuery);

                ParameterList selectList = new ParameterList(Auth.NAMESPACE_COMPLEX_TYPE, "DimensionsSelect");
//selectBox.getList - выдает список параметров(в виде объекта) из которых просто берем параметры как строки
                for (Object item : selectBox.getList()) {

                    Parameter parameter = new Parameter(Auth.NAMESPACE_COMPLEX_TYPE, "Parameter");
                    PropertyInfo propertyName = new PropertyInfo();
                    propertyName.setName("Name");
                    propertyName.setType(PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS);
                    propertyName.setValue((((ParameterCus) item).getName()));
                    propertyName.setNamespace(Auth.NAMESPACE_COMPLEX_TYPE);
                    parameter.addProperty(propertyName);
                    PropertyInfo propertyValue = new PropertyInfo();
                    propertyValue.setName("Value");
                    propertyValue.setType(PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS);
                    propertyValue.setValue((((ParameterCus) item).getValue()));
                    propertyValue.setNamespace(Auth.NAMESPACE_COMPLEX_TYPE);
                    parameter.addProperty(propertyValue);

                    PropertyInfo propertyType = new PropertyInfo();
                    propertyType.setName("Type");
                    propertyType.setType(PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS);
                    propertyType.setValue((((ParameterCus) item).getType()));
                    propertyType.setNamespace(Auth.NAMESPACE_COMPLEX_TYPE);
                    parameter.addProperty(propertyType);
                    PropertyInfo propertyTypeSearch = new PropertyInfo();
                    propertyTypeSearch.setName("TypeSearch");
                    propertyTypeSearch.setType(PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS);
                    propertyTypeSearch.setValue((((ParameterCus) item).getTypeSearch()));
                    propertyTypeSearch.setNamespace(Auth.NAMESPACE_COMPLEX_TYPE);
                    parameter.addProperty(propertyTypeSearch);

                    selectList.addSoapObject(parameter);

                }

                request.addSoapObject(selectList);


                    ParameterList inserList = new ParameterList(Auth.NAMESPACE_COMPLEX_TYPE, "DimensionsResources");
  //insetrBox.getList() - просто возвращает список параметров(объектов), которые содержат аргументы в виде строк 
                    for (Object item : insertBox.getList()) {

                        Parameter parameter = new Parameter(Auth.NAMESPACE_COMPLEX_TYPE, "Parameter");
                        PropertyInfo propertyName = new PropertyInfo();
                        propertyName.setName("Name");
                        propertyName.setType(PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS);
                        propertyName.setValue((((ParameterCus) item).getName()));
                        propertyName.setNamespace(Auth.NAMESPACE_COMPLEX_TYPE);
                        parameter.addProperty(propertyName);
                        PropertyInfo propertyValue = new PropertyInfo();
                        propertyValue.setName("Value");
                        propertyValue.setType(PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS);
                        propertyValue.setValue((((ParameterCus) item).getValue()));
                        propertyValue.setNamespace(Auth.NAMESPACE_COMPLEX_TYPE);
                        parameter.addProperty(propertyValue);
                        PropertyInfo propertyType = new PropertyInfo();
                        propertyType.setName("Type");
                        propertyType.setType(PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS);
                        propertyType.setValue((((ParameterCus) item).getType()));
                        propertyType.setNamespace(Auth.NAMESPACE_COMPLEX_TYPE);
                        parameter.addProperty(propertyType);
                        PropertyInfo propertyTypeSearch = new PropertyInfo();
                        propertyTypeSearch.setName("TypeSearch");
                        propertyTypeSearch.setType(PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS);
                        propertyTypeSearch.setValue((((ParameterCus) item).getTypeSearch()));
                        propertyTypeSearch.setNamespace(Auth.NAMESPACE_COMPLEX_TYPE);
                        parameter.addProperty(propertyTypeSearch);

                        inserList.addSoapObject(parameter);

                    }


                    request.addSoapObject(inserList);
                } else {
                    //Ответвление на случай если второй параметр не был передан, так у меня осуществляется удаление в 1с

                }
                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                envelope.dotNet = true;
                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                envelope.addMapping(Auth.NAMESPACE_COMPLEX_TYPE, "ParameterList", new ParameterList().getClass());
                envelope.addMapping(Auth.NAMESPACE_COMPLEX_TYPE, "Parameter",new Parameter().getClass());


                envelope.implicitTypes = true;

                HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL_WEB_SERVICE);
                androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
                String result = "";
                try {
                    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);//headers - можно добавить для авторизации, куки или базик хттп авторизация

                    Object alsResponse = envelope.getResponse();
                    if (alsResponse instanceof SoapFault) {
                        Log.d("Test", "fault " + alsResponse.toString());

                    } else if (alsResponse instanceof SoapObject) {
                        SoapObject responseObject = ((SoapObject) alsResponse).newInstance();
                        responseObject.getAttributeCount();
                        responseObject.getPropertyCount();responseObject.getAttributeCount() + " counb_property=" + responseObject.getPropertyCount());
                        SoapObject parameterList = (SoapObject) responseObject.getProperty(1);
                        result = parameterList.toString();
                    } else if (alsResponse instanceof SoapPrimitive) {
                        result = ((SoapPrimitive) alsResponse).getValue().toString();
                    } else {
                        Log.d("Test", "WTF?");
                    }
                } catch (java.lang.ClassCastException e) {

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    String erro_retult = e.toString() + " " + e.getMessage() + " " + androidHttpTransport.requestDump;
                    return erro_retult;
                }
                return result;
```

Все эти действия я осуществляю в AsynckTask. Parameter и ParameterList это просто наследники SoapObject, в них ничего не переопределенно. Но они нужны в таком виде, потому что дают имя классов корректное. Мое SOAP_ACTION вот тут:

```
<operation name="ModifyInformationRegister">
<soapbind:operation style="document" soapAction="http://ws1c.xxxxx.ru#WebService:ModifyInformationRegister"/>
<input>
<soapbind:body use="literal"/>
</input>
<output>
<soapbind:body use="literal"/>
</output>
</operation>
```